# How to protect ports 7000 and 9000 in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Could you guide me how to disable or password protect the YugabyteDB UI interfaces on port 7000 and 9000? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can't password protect the UI within YugabyteDB. You can block the port with your firewall. And then expose it behind a reverse proxy webserver like `traefik`,`envoy`,`nginx`,`caddy`.